# How to send scheduled emails

Tags: .net, vb.net, email, scheduled-tasks

I am building a desktop app with vb.net and i want to send scheduled email messages. For example i want to send mails in a specific time of a day. Is there any way to do this? Also, is there any way to send these messages even if my app is closed? Thanks!!

Comment: What part of your program have you tackled? Are there any specific issues?

Comment: i tried to do this with this libray http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/ , but i don't know if it is what i want..

Answer (score 2):

You can put a console app or any executable in windows task scheduler, you can set it to wake computer or even better publish it to a server running constantly

Comment: so, i should create a console app and when the time comes it will be executed sending emails? Can a console app run on background? (user doesn't see the process)

Answer (score 0):

Please. create a windows service is running in as a service in background, which constantly reads database email tables where you store email information, and pending email can be sene as per schedule time.

Please, more details from below link :
http://www.codeguru.com/vb/gen/vb_system/services/article.php/c4825/Creating-a-Windows-Service-in-VBNET.htm